# Casting int on a c++ logic layer

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

I am new to c++ and as for now I have quite a heavy task on my work, I have a gui made in wpf and I need to send parameters from the gui to the c++ the (which as for now I already handled)

My problem is that on the c++ layer I get the info as a BYTE* I need to reinterprete the values to their "original" state (the first translation from ont\float to byte array is being made on the C# level using the static BitConvertor class) as for now I used this little method -

```
void GetNextValue(byte* bytes, deque<BYTE> *buffer)
{
    bytes[3] = buffer->front(); 
    buffer->pop_front();
    bytes[2] = buffer->front(); 
    buffer->pop_front();
    bytes[1] = buffer->front(); 
    buffer->pop_front();
    bytes[0] = buffer->front(); 
    buffer->pop_front();
}
```

But for an integer value of 1 I get a really high number, on the other hand going directly for the int value in the whole buffer will yield the correct answer...(i.e. int x = pBuffer[4]), any help or suggestions will be gladly accepted..

BTW-
I used

```
_rxBuffer.insert( _rxBuffer.end(), pBuffer, pBuffer + nLength);
```

To convert the BYTE* of data to -

```
deque<BYTE> _rxBuffer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of `byte[4]` you can just convert it to integer by this:

```
byte bytes[4];
int value = *(int*)bytes;
```

But beware, depending on endianess of your platform you may or may need not swap bytes order (try to replace 3<>0 and 2<>1 in bytes).

Comment: Holly molly...I would never paid attention to that if you would not mentioned it...TNX ALOT BRO!